# Unity Blue T in TMP Mesh Box instead of text

Tags: unity-game-engine

All I can get is this blue T in the TMP box. This is after I reloaded Unity - before that, i could see text in scene view but not game view.

A screenshot is below. Anyone else experienced this or know how to fix? I am new to Unity btw.

TRIED:

- Reloading Unity
- Installing all packages
- Checking package manager
- Moving TMP object out of canvas and into main hierarchy

Nothing changed, except that originally i could at least see the text in scene view and now i just get a blue T.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a TextMeshPro_UGUI Component, it is meant to be used in a Canvas like the other UGUI elements.

The blue T is the gizmo that shows the type of the Component in the scene view and makes it clickable if no other visual element is attached to it.

If you want to render the text in the world, you have to spawn a GameObject with a regular TextMeshPro component.

---

See [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObjects.html) for a proper overview of the two text types.